# Generate C/C++ DLL using visual studio code

Tags: dll, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to use Visual Studio Code to generate a DLL file?

In Visual Studio Community Edition, there is a wizard that provides options for setting up a project to output a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but if this helps there you go:

if using GCC with mingW32 or mingw64
the following command should be used.

if using windows:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared objectfile.o -o outputfile.dll
```

if using mac or linux:

```
gcc -shared objectfile.o -o outputfile.dll
```

Comment: gcc -shared objectfile.o -o outputfile.dll also works on windows. Thanks for the answer